# Is there a way to reset or hide mastery score on champions

Tags: league-of-legends

I main as Kayle often, so my mastery score displays as about 850k and rising.

All the rest of the people (except for once in a while it seems) have 10k and less.

This is giving my lane opposition insight into how much I play as Kayle on top lane, so the more observant ones play safer than most would.

Is there a way to reset/hide my mastery score?   I'm fine with still showing the mastery 6 token, this only tells part of the story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although there is no official answer from any Riot employee, multiple discussion threads and my own research have hinted that it is **not possible to hide or reset Mastery Points  at the moment**.

Sources:

- [Boards post 1](https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/player-behavior-moderation/jrUavvvh-hide-champion-mastery-points-during-loading-screen)
- [Boards post 2](https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/general-discussion/hlMvqe1W-can-we-have-an-option-to-hide-our-mastery-points)
- [Boards post 3](https://boards.euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/champions-gameplay-en/AWNO8KYi-i-want-to-be-able-to-remove-my-mastery-level-above-5-if-i-want-to) suggesting the possibility of removing Mastery 5+, which dates back to 2017
- [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/a1cear/is_showing_mastery_points_on_everyones_champ_in/)
- Self-digging in the League client

Comment: I think there's a new feature in League now, "Mastery locked".  But I dont readily see the option to hide it.  I main Kayle, one-trick style, and now have almost 900K mastery which brings unwanted attention.

Comment: @enorl76 "Mastery locked" hides mastery on the other end of the spectrum. If your Mastery score is less than level 4, it is not displayed. Supposedly this is to prevent people from flaming players who are first-timing a champion, or playing someone they have only played a handful of times before.

Comment: Additionally, I think it's most of the playerbase acknowledges that a high mastery score does not equate to skill level. It's simply a counter for how often you've played the champ. There are Yasuo players with 1m+ mastery points stuck in Bronze, and there are Challenger players who do well on champs they've never played before. Rank is significantly more indicative of skill than mastery score.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new account, but no seriously I don't think there is a way to hide your mastery score. I wanted to do it for my main account because like you, I used to main a champ (fiddle supp) to the point where people just wouldn't do anything but cs against me. Not that I was a high rank but people just got turned off by 200k+ points. A quick internet search to show that this has been a topic for years, leads me to believe riot does not care at this point. But hey, they give a lot of champs now for new players, so that's a plus.